# @propertyWrapper seg fault

Tags: swift, swift5

I am trying to write a propertyWrapper (simplified for exemple), but when I use it, I got a seg fault 11

```swift
@propertyWrapper
struct Password {

    private(set) var value: String = ""

    var wrappedValue: String {
        get { value }
        set { value = newValue }
    }

    init(initialValue: String) {
        self.wrappedValue = initialValue
    }
}
```

When I apply to this struct I got seg fault 11

```swift
struct AppUserDefaults {
    @Password()
    static var password: String
}
```

If I remove `static` it work. I don't understand why I cannot use on static var. propertyWrapper can be applied on static [see](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/property-wrappers/) and I use @UserDefault on the same struct